# Why my simulation of chat service write wrong content?

Tags: c, simulation, fifo

I'm simulating a chat service on C language I send an mensage to server side like "U:username,password; to login an user but when I asks who is online it print's n times (Let n be number of users online) the name of user who asks! What is not the expected behavior. Someone can tell me why?

server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <linux/stat.h>

#define FIFO_FILE "MYFIFO"

typedef struct online {
 char* user;
 struct online* next;
} online;

typedef struct users{
 char* name;
 char* password;
} users;

online* begin=NULL;
online* end=NULL;
FILE *fp;
void start_server();

void add_online(char* user);

void realocate_end();

void remove_online(char* user);

char* user_access(char* s);



void who_online();

void free_all();

int find_username(char* user);

void add_user_regist(char* user,char* password);

users* find_user_regist(char* user, char* password);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 if(argc>1){
  char password[50];
  char password2[50];

  printf("Password? ");
  scanf("%s",password);
  printf("Repita a password? ");
  scanf("%s",password2);

  if(strcmp(password,password2)!=0){
   printf("Passwords diferentes!\n");
   exit(1);
  }

  if(find_username(argv[1])){
   printf("Utilizador ja existe\n");
   exit(1);
  }
  add_user_regist(argv[1],password);
  printf("Utilizador %s adicionado.\n",argv[1]);
  exit(0);
 }


 char readbuf[250];

 /* Create the FIFO if it does not exist */
 umask(0);
 mknod(FIFO_FILE, S_IFIFO|0666, 0);
 printf("Servidor iniciado.\nEm modo de espera de mensagens\n");

 while(1)
 {
  fp = fopen(FIFO_FILE, "r");
  fgets(readbuf, 250, fp);
  fclose(fp);
  if(readbuf[0]=='U')
   user_access(readbuf);
  if(readbuf[0]=='W')
   who_online();
  printf("Received string: %s\n",readbuf);


 }
return(0);
}



void realocate_end(){
 online* tmp=begin;
 while(tmp!=NULL){
  if(tmp->next==NULL)
   end=tmp;
  tmp=tmp->next;
 }
}

void remove_online(char* user){
 online* tmp=begin;
 char path[100];
 sprintf(path,"/tmp/chatroom_%s",user);
 unlink(path);
 while(tmp!=NULL){
  if(tmp->user==user && tmp->user == end->user){
   free(end);
   end=NULL;
   realocate_end();
  }
  else if(tmp->user==user && tmp->user == begin->user ){
   begin=begin->next;
   free(tmp);
   break;

  }
  else if(tmp->next->user ==user){
   online* tmp2 = tmp->next->next;
   free(tmp->next);
   tmp->next = tmp2;
   realocate_end();
   break;
  }
  tmp=tmp->next;
 }
}

void add_online(char* user){
 online* tmp = (online*)malloc(sizeof(online));
 tmp->user = user;
 tmp->next = NULL;


 if(begin==NULL){
  begin = tmp;
  end=tmp;
 }
 else{
  end->next=tmp;
  end=end->next;
 }
}

void who_online(){
 online* tmp = begin;
 while(tmp!=NULL){
  printf("%s\n",tmp->user);
  tmp=tmp->next;
 }
}

void free_all(){
 while(begin!=NULL){
  online* tmp = begin->next;
  free(begin);
  begin = tmp;
 }
}

int find_username(char* user){
 FILE* fp;
 char line[50];
 fp=fopen("./regist", "r");
 while(fscanf(fp,"%s",line)!=EOF){
  char* name=strtok(line,",");
  if(strcmp(name,user)==0){
   fclose(fp);
   return 1;
  }
 }
 return 0;
}

char* user_access(char* s){
 int i=0 ,begin=2;
 strtok(s,":");
 char* username=strtok(NULL,",");
 char* password=strtok(NULL,";");

 add_online(username);


 } 

 users* find_user_regist(char* user, char* password){
  FILE* fp;
  char line[50];

  users* tmp = (users*) malloc(sizeof(users));

  fp=fopen("./regist", "r");
  while(fscanf(fp,"%s",line)!=EOF){
   tmp->name =strtok(line,",");
   tmp->password = strtok(NULL,";");
   if(strcmp(tmp->name,user)==0 && strcmp(tmp->password,password)==0 ){
    fclose(fp);
    return tmp;
   }


  }
  fclose(fp);
  return NULL;
 }

 void add_user_regist(char* user,char* password){
  FILE* fp;
  fp=fopen("./regist", "a");
  if(fp==NULL)
   fp=fopen("./regist", "w");
  fprintf(fp,"%s,%s;\n",user,password);
  fclose(fp);
 }
```

client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <linux/stat.h>


#define FIFO_FILE "MYFIFO"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;

    char user[50];
    char password[50];

    if(argc==1){
     printf("Não escolheu utilizador\n");
     exit(0);
    }

    sprintf(user,"%s",argv[1]);
    printf("Password:\n");
    scanf("%s",password);
    getchar();

    char mensagem[250];

    if((fp = fopen(FIFO_FILE, "w")) == NULL) {
     perror("fopen");
     exit(1);
    }
    char path [100] ;

    strcpy(path,".");
    strcat(path,user);
    umask(0);
    mknod(path, S_IFIFO|0666, 0);

    sprintf(mensagem,"U:%s,%s;",user,password);
    fputs(mensagem, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    while(1){

     printf("**Menu**\n1) Listar utilizadores online\n2) Mandar SMS a um utilizador\n3) Logout\n\n");

     char opcao;
     scanf("%c",&opcao);
     char lixo=getchar();

     if(opcao!='1' && opcao!='2' && opcao!='3')
       continue;
     if(opcao=='1'){
      if((fp = fopen(FIFO_FILE, "w")) == NULL) {
       perror("fopen");
       exit(1);
     }
     sprintf(mensagem,"W:%s;",user);
     fputs(mensagem, fp);
     fclose(fp);
     }
     else if(opcao=='2'){

     if((fp = fopen(FIFO_FILE, "w")) == NULL) {
      perror("fopen");
      exit(1);
     }

     memset(mensagem,0,sizeof(mensagem));
     scanf("%s",mensagem);
     char lixo=getchar();
     fputs(mensagem, fp);
     fclose(fp);
     }
    else if(opcao=='3'){
     break;
    }

   }



  return(0);
 }
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a debugging service. Please use a debugger to help narrow down where the problem might be. But first make sure that all strings are properly terminated, and remember that pipes (which a FIFO is) is a *streaming* communication method, without any set message boundaries. That means a receive might receive less than a full message, or more, and you need to implement some kind of protocol on top of the stream to introduce message boundaries yourself (by e.g. having start/stop sequences, or a fixed-length message size header).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a result of you forgetting to allocate new memory to store the username for each individual user. The way you do it now allocates new memory for a pointer to a string for each individual user - not the actual string.

If you follow the path the value you store in the struct through the function calls you will see that every record points to the `readbuf` arrays

Consider this:

```
char readbuf[250] = "U:name,password;"
user_access(readbuf);
```

In user_access `char *s` points to the start of the string, namely `U`. The second call to `strtok` returns the pointer to the beginning of the username `n` and replaces `,` with a null-terminator.

At the time of the call to `add_online` the buffer now looks something like this `"U\0name\0password\0\0"` with `username` pointing to the c-string `"name"` still stored in `readbuf`

When you create a new node in the linked list you simply assign the pointer to that c-string in the readbuf, as such the usernames will change depending on what is in your buffer. As the W command is only one character the last username sent to the server will be intact in the buffer.

To fix this you can simply allocate new memory for each username and copy the strings.

```
void add_online(char* user){
    online* tmp = (online*) malloc(sizeof(online));
    tmp->user = (char*) malloc(strlen(user)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(tmp->user, user);
    tmp->next = NULL;


    if (begin==NULL){
        begin = tmp;
        end=tmp;
    }
    else {
        end->next=tmp;
        end=end->next;
    }
}
```

Similarly you should free the allocated memory for the username when freeing the struct